# Migration of URL schema between servers

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, dns

I'm the sysadmin of a web site that is being migrated from a URL schema of plain HTML files to a dynamic Content Management System.

As example the old URLS are like www.example.com/books/somefolder/book31Chapter23.html and the new ones are like www.cms.example.com/x?book=31

The site is hosted in two servers, one 'old' serving the static old URLS at the main domain www.example.com and one 'new' with the CMS at a subdomain www.cms.example.com.

Web servers are nginx and the CMS is written in yii (PHP) but this shouldn't matter conceptually for this question.

There are many URLS and only part of the content has been migrated to the new CMS, so we have three cases:

1. user requesting old URL of content that hasn't been migrated: in
   this case the web server (nginx) serves the content from the 'old'
   server.
2. user requesting new URL (migrated content): this is served
   directly by the new server
3. user requesting old URL of content that has been migrated: the
   request reaches the old server. There's a mapping list and we have
   nginx do a temporaty redirect from the old url to the new url, so
   traffic is redirected to the CMS in the new server.

So far this has been working and as new content is migrated the redirect mapping list is updated.

The problem is that I'd like the second server with the CMS to serve content as the main domain example.com and not a subdomain cms.example.com , that and also the temporary redirects seem to affect SEO for Google etc.

Ideally I want in the 3rd case to do a permanent redirect to the new CMS URL schema without using a subdomain, noting also that currently the CMS is hosted in a different server (I could merge everything in one if needed). Also for the 2nd case users would go to the new URL using the naked domain and not a subdomain.

How do I achieve this in the current set up (using nginx redirects, DNS or whatever is needed)? is there a better set up for migrating urls between two servers?

thanks!

Comment: did you try using a temporary redirect of the 3rd case? it would tell google not to save the new URL, otherwise your second option would be doing a proxy pass, the problem is how many URL's are we talking about? the more they are the harder handling this would be.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, as stated "we have nginx do a temporary redirect", that's how it's currently working. I have thousands of URLs to migrate.